# JBoss classpath issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, classpath, jboss7.x

In the java code under /class I have

```
str_url = "/jasperReports/report.jasper";
url = getClass().getResource(str_url);
```

And the actual `report.jasper` template is under

```
Application.war\WEB-INF\classes\jasperReports
```

From the war file, but now the application gives me following exceptions:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Windows\System32\content\Application.war\WEB-INF\classes\jasperReports\report.jasper
```

So what's going on and why does the application look for the template under `System folder`, that's not a temporary or cache folder at all.

### UPDATE

I do get exception when deploy the application:

```
15:29:43,359 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component examples.ShowSource due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.ShowSource from [Module "deployment.Application.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
```

Comment: try "./jasperReports/report.jasper";

Comment: Try to redeploy your project after deleting the temp, log and data file in stand alone folder

Comment: @user 2511414 Thank you. Add spot but still not working..

Comment: @Ruchira Thank you. I tried, remove project folder under tmp and redeploy...not working..

Comment: @Dreamerwhen you deploy the war file did you get any errors

Comment: and would you try this too, 'str_url ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/jasperReports/report.jasper")';

Comment: @Ruchira I do have exception, just updated the post.

Comment: @Dreamer seems to be your project not bundled properly.

Comment: @Ruchira Thanks could you please be more specific?

Comment: @user 2511414 thanks but that doesn't work on this case..

Comment: the last thing I would say here is implement a resource that would locate the file with context and map it in web.xml, and simply reach the resource(context look up, injection) and get the file

Answer (score 0):

@Dreamer Do not think  the jboss AS reads directly  the classes and other things from war file. In fact  jboss uses **temp** in run time and puts (or convert) the war files content to **“..\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp..”**.

for example if your war file is in following path:

```
D:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments\myApp.war
```

in run time we have something like this:

```
D:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp4b7f8b311765d81a\content-5bbc912a62a7929e
```

(Last path obviously changes after any run).

Now suppose we have one class called “Test.java” and we want to obtain its real path by something like this:

```
String projectUrl = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
```

The projectUrl is :

```
   vfs:/D:/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/bin/content/myApp.war/WEB-INF/classes
```

I think this path not practical thing that you want! It is important that we know the real path of war file changes in runtime:).

I had the same problem. I had one application that we used JSF and I wanted to load one jrxml file. I solved it by :

```
String this.projectUrl = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("one file");//to get my current app path in temp!
```

and

```
myFilePath = this.projectUrl + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "classes" + File.separator + "reportResources" + File.separator + "test.jrxml";//and read it;
```

And load my file like this:

```
 ClassLoader loader = TestClass.class.getClassLoader();
 InputStream reportStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(myFilePath);//and load it
```

I hope this can help you;